# Can't boot Windows 10 after installing Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-10

I installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 10, followed the instructions without deviation and now I can't boot Windows. The error message is boot loader is missing. I can still access my Windows files through Ubuntu, but booting Windows is not an option since installing Ubuntu. How can I fix this?